# Save Images in Room Database

Tags: database, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I want to save small images in my room database and I have two issues:

1. How do I save an image in my database?
2. How do I save multiple images in my database?

I tried saving a bitmap in the way recommended by the developers page (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data)

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "image_table")
data class ImgMod(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var invoiceId: Long = 0L,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    var single_img: Bitmap?
): Parcelable
```

However, I receive the following error:

`Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.`

Secondly, I would like to save multiple images in one database entry. But I receive the same error with the following snippets:

```
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageList")
    var img_list: ArrayList<BitMap>
```

or decoded bitmap as a String

```
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageList")
    var decoded_img_list: ArrayList<String>
```

I am sorry if this is a very basic question. But how do I have to configure the database/process the data to an image list?

Thank you in advance,
rot8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very simple way to get images into the database (although I personally discourage it) would be to base-64 encode the bitmaps into a String and put it into a row of the database.

Take in account that bitmaps are very memory heavy; and base64 encoding something increases it's size some more so be careful when loading a bunch of images... I do also think Room and SQLite supports binary data as blobs, so you could just declare a column as `ByteArray` and it should just work.

What I've been doing in my projects is to write them into the internal or external storage of my app and then store the reference `Uri` as a `String` to later be able to retrieve the image from disk.

Something that I discourage even more is to stuff more than one value per row; having a list of stuff inside a coulmn in SQL is definetely not a pattern you should follow. Creating a "join" table should be simple enough or simply an extra column you could use to group them by should be easy enough, right?

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. :) You persuaded me, that storing multiple value/images in one cell is not good practice. 

But I have a basic question about saving image in a filesystem vs saving it in a database. In my specific project I want to save these images for a time of at least 10 years. Would you still recommend using a file-system? Because from my naive point-of-view a database seems to be safer.

Comment: How would you say it's it safer? Maybe something is going over my head but if the user "clears app data" databases and internal files are blown away. If I really want to keep an image for a very long time I would upload it to some online server and run a synchronization task every day ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you're worried the user accesses those files make sure you use internal storage instead of external storage.

Comment: Yes, I plan on saving the data on a server, and I thought its more tidy if I only have a SQL database to maintain compared to a database and a file server.

I didn't know the difference between internal and external storage, thank you.

Comment: It's more or less the same deal... The big issue comes that when you pull the images from the database you're pulling the entire image (which is RAM heavy). If you use the file system, libraries like Picasso and Glide do smart things when loading them by doing some magic maths and the size of the image view where you are trying to put them on. They also do caching to load images even faster which is a really cool benefit from using those.